# FullCalender - Reset Event color when second event is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, calendar

I am wonderin how do you reset the event color when you click a second event? Right now I am changing the color when you click an event. When a second event is clicked the first events new color is the same. How do I reset it to the default color?

**My Code:**

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

   jQuery(this).css('background-color', '#b3ffb3');

}
```

Comment: You had to cache it or add a class on the event (when you adding style on it) that can help you to find it easier for removing its style and turn it to normal, if you provide HTML element i can help you more

Comment: There is no html other the `<div id='calendar'></div>` The calender is being renderd thru JS. Solved it like this thou. `if (globalEventVariable !== null) {
                        globalEventVariable.css('background-color', '#33cc33')
                    }
                    var currentEvent = jQuery(this);
                    currentEvent.css('background-color', '#b3ffb3');
                    globalEventVariable = currentEvent;` Open for improvments.

Comment: Make a screenshot or copy/paste calendar element when you inspect that (right click on element and click on inspect, so browser will show you the content of the element)

Answer (score 0):

**Please** *update/edit* your question with calendar element.

This will give you idea about how you can achieve that:

**HTML** (calendar element[supposedly]):

```
<table id="calendar">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="event">2 (event)</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="event">7 (event)</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS/Jquery**:

```
jQuery('#calendar').on('click', '.event', function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('special')){
        $(this).parents('#calendar').find('.event.special').removeClass('special');
        $(this).addClass('special');
    }
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.special {color: red;}
```

**P.S**: in this way you will add a class `.special` to events which will clicked and also check to remove that class from other events. So at a time just one event has style and by clicking on another event it will lost its style and style will add to new one.

**Sec P.S**: You can add any jquery function after `addClass` and `removeClass` for exp:

```
jQuery('#calendar').on('click', '.event', function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('special')){
        $(this).parents('#calendar').find('.event.special').removeClass('special').css('background-color', '');
        $(this).addClass('special').css('background-color', '#b3ffb3');
    }
});
```